# how to show list of items into data grid view c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms Application I am working on and am using the language C#. I have a list of items that I want to put into a Data Grid View. Here is the code I tried :

```
        List<double> m2 = T.ALLDATIX;
        var list = new BindingList<double>(m2);
        var source = new BindingSource(list, null);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = source ;
```

Comment: what is happening now?

Comment: Make sure properties are public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS LINE SOLVED THE PROBLEM

```
       this.dataGridView1.DataSource = m2.Select(k => new { Value = k }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
var bindingSource = new BindingSource(){ DataSource = m2 };
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

[See docs for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: Do you have any items in `m2` list?

Comment: 40 items  . i checked them using a break point ant add watch

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I assume that the problem is, that the dataGridView does need objects (containing properties) to work properly.

```
// Define a container class
class Container
{
   public double Data { get; set; }
} 

// convert list of double to BindingList of Container Objects
var list = T.ALLDATIX.Select(q => new Container { Data = q }).ToBindingList();

// Assign data
grid.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use the datasource. Try something like this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = list.ToList();
```